# Java file setWritable in JVM with privileges

Tags: java, linux, apache-flink

I'm building Apache Flink from source using Gitlab CI with image `java:8u111-jdk`, and find that tests on file permissions failed because file permissions are not respected.

One of the unit tests is like:

```
    @Test
    public void testDeleteDirectory() throws Exception {

        // deleting a non-existent file should not cause an error

        File doesNotExist = new File(tmp.newFolder(), "abc");
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(doesNotExist);

        // deleting a write protected file should throw an error

        File cannotDeleteParent = tmp.newFolder();
        File cannotDeleteChild = new File(cannotDeleteParent, "child");

        try {
            assumeTrue(cannotDeleteChild.createNewFile());
            assumeTrue(cannotDeleteParent.setWritable(false));
            assumeTrue(cannotDeleteChild.setWritable(false));

            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(cannotDeleteParent);
            fail("this should fail with an exception");
        }
        catch (AccessDeniedException ignored) {
            // this is expected
        }
        finally {
            //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
            cannotDeleteParent.setWritable(true);
            //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
            cannotDeleteChild.setWritable(true);
        }
    }
```

And the test result is:

```
testDeleteDirectory(org.apache.flink.util.FileUtilsTest)  Time elapsed: 0.022 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: this should fail with an exception
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FileUtilsTest.testDeleteDirectory(FileUtilsTest.java:129)
```

When I dug deeper into the codes, I found the following statements in `java.io.File` :

> On some platforms it may be possible to start the Java virtual machine with special privileges that allow it to modify files that disallow write operations.

So I suspect it's something wrong with the CI environment. How can I further debug the problem? Thanks!

Environment:

- docker image: java:8u111-jdk
- OS kernel: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64
- distribution: Debian 8
- JDK version: openjdk 1.8.0_111

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that we run this code as root user, so we are able to delete write protected files.